# Can this theory be defined in FOL(=,$\in$)?

Tags: first-order-logic, alternative-set-theories

The question I'm asking here is purely technical.
For the below mentioned theory, can it be defined in first order logic with equality and membership, or it necessitates adding '$\operatorname {stage}$' as a primitive one place predicate symbol to that language.

**Axioms**

**Extensionality:** $X \subset Y \land Y \subset X \implies X=Y$

**Foundation:** $,\exists x: \phi(x), \implies \exists x: \phi(x) \land \forall y \, (\phi(y) \implies  y \not\in x)$,

where '$y$' does't occur free in $\phi(x)$, and $\phi(y)$ is the formula obtained from $\phi(x)$ by merely replacing all occurrences of the symbol '$x$' by the symbol '$y$'.

***Define:*** $\operatorname {stage} (X) \iff \\ \forall y \ [y \in X \iff \exists Y (\operatorname {stage} (Y) \land Y \subsetneq X \land y \subseteq Y)] $

**Separation:** $\exists x: x=\{y \in A \mid \phi\}$; if '$x$' is not free in $\phi$.

**Hierarchy:** $\forall x \exists \operatorname {stage} S: x \in S$

**Infinity:** $\exists X: X \neq \emptyset \land \forall x \in X \, (\{x\} \in X)$

Comment: can you explain the idea `stage' is meant to refer to here? eg do you have a specific model of this theory in mind?

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom, 'Stage' here means a stage of the cumulative hierarchy, it is an iterative power of the empty set, the theory in mind is similar to Zermelo + Rank presented by Holmes, see: randall-holmes.github.io/Drafts/hierarchy.pdf (skim classes from it). $V_{\omega+\omega}$ is a model of this theory. Related is Scott-Potter set theory (but without Ur-elements).